# DIV saindo da tela

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu já vi varias vezes uma div meio que saindo da tela, e como não vou saber explicar direito, vou mostrar uma foto de uma exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu imaginei que seria com box-shadow, mas nao consegui fazer.
Nao quero fazer o mesmo design do rapaz, até pq nao vou "roubar" o trabalho dele, mas queria saber como que faz pra ficar assim, saindo da tela.

Link: https://dribbble.com/shots/4150795-Conceptual-Dashboard-UI-Analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse efeito usa `box-shadow` sim, mas tb usa `transform:scale(1.2);`

Veja nesse Snipper um exemplo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #3b414d;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
background-color: pink;
transform: scale(1.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**Se quiser o efeito apenas quando fizer o `:hover`** basta substituir o `.container div:nth-child(2){}` por `.container div:hover{}`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #3b414d;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.container div:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: isso. mas tem como deixar eles maiores sem acontecer uma quebra? pq quando mudei para .container div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
} ocorreu uma quebra

Comment: @Maria faz assim, tira o `display:inline-block;` do `.container div` e na classe `.container` acrescenta `display:flex;` que vai resolver. Mas tudo depende do seu projeto... Onde vão ficar na página, se é responsivo etc. Esse modelo que eu fiz é só um exemplo, não é a solução perfeita para todos os casos...